Carnot efficiency for IC engine
Consider
$$e= \frac{T_h-T_c}{T_h}.$$
What is $T_c$ in Carnot efficiency for internal combustion engine, atmosphere or exhaust temperature?
If $T_c$ is atmosphere temperature, does that mean engine is more efficient at cold days?

The internal combustion engine does not operate a Carnot cycle, not even approximately, so its efficiency will not be given by this simple formula. However if you did have a Carnot cycle involving gas in a cylinder then $T_c$ would be the temperature of the gas itself in the part of the cycle where heat is being expelled. This would correspond roughly to the exhaust gas in the internal combustion engine. I guess this would be affected slightly by the weather conditions. But the temperature of the engine will also affect other things such as viscosity of oil and size of gap around the piston, affecting the amount of friction. After taking everything into account the efficiency could go either way. I expect the engine is most efficient in ordinary weather but I don't know.
